# How to create a VCard with a picture embedded?

Tags: vcf-vcard

I have been working to generate a VCard and a subsequent QR Code using excel macros. At the moment I am able to input data such as names, job, organization, contact number etc in my spreadsheet and this gets called perfectly by my macro. However, when it comes to the picture I have no idea how to approach this matter. I've seen mention of using base64 but does that mean I would need to convert the JPEG to base64 using a converter?

The portion of my macro dealing with the generation of my VCard is as follows:

For intRow = 2 To 4

```
    strFname = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact_Info").Range("A" & intRow).Text)
    strLname = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact_Info").Range("B" & intRow).Text)
    strCellPhone = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact_Info").Range("C" & intRow).Text)
    strBusPhone = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact_Info").Range("D" & intRow).Text)
    strEmail = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact_Info").Range("E" & intRow).Text)
    strCompn = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact_Info").Range("F" & intRow).Text)
    strJobTitle = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact_Info").Range("G" & intRow).Text)
    strDept = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact_Info").Range("H" & intRow).Text)
    strWeb = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact_Info").Range("I" & intRow).Text)
    strAdd = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact_Info").Range("J" & intRow).Text)
    
    strVCF = ""
    strVCF = strVCF & "BEGIN:VCARD" & Chr(10)
    strVCF = strVCF & "VERSION:3.0" & Chr(10)
    
    strVCF = strVCF & "N:" & strLname & ";" & strFname & Chr(10)
    strVCF = strVCF & "ORG:" & strCompn & Chr(10)
    strVCF = strVCF & "TITLE:" & strJobTitle & " | " & strDept & Chr(10)
    strVCF = strVCF & "FN:" & strFname & " " & strLname & Chr(10)
    
    strVCF = strVCF & "TEL;TYPE=CELL:" & strCellPhone & Chr(10)
    strVCF = strVCF & "TEL;TYPE=WORK:" & strBusPhone & Chr(10)
    strVCF = strVCF & "EMAIL:" & strEmail & Chr(10)
    strVCF = strVCF & "URL:" & strWeb & Chr(10)
    strVCF = strVCF & "ADR:" & strAdd & Chr(10)
    
    
    strVCF = strVCF & "END:VCARD"
```

I have seen mention of using "PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=JPEG:".

I have tried using this but this doesn't appear to work. The way I treated my photo addition is by creating a column where I add my photo and then I have a portion in my macro in which I call that column similar to the above and then I called it in my VCard portion of the code as "PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=JPEG:". I'd appreciate any assistance, I am new to all this and have just been trying to learn on my own.